# I can resolve hostnames but I can't load the webpages of said host?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm on windows 10 pro. When I do `nslookup speedtest.net` the results are

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup speedtest.net
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    speedtest.net
Addresses:  2a04:4e42:200::230
          2a04:4e42::230
          2a04:4e42:400::230
          2a04:4e42:600::230
          151.101.64.230
          151.101.192.230
          151.101.128.230
          151.101.0.230
```

When I ping speedtest.net I get

```
Pinging speedtest.net [151.101.64.230] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.64.230: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=58
Reply from 151.101.64.230: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=58
Reply from 151.101.64.230: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=58
Reply from 151.101.64.230: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 151.101.64.230:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 20ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 21ms

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

When I open firefox or chrome and go to speedtest.net the webpage won't load.

[image]

When I try to go to speedtest.net on my iphone it won't connect either. Arris cable modem and pfsense router. I rebooted both, 3 times. I thought the issue was because I installed Snort but I deleted it and rebooted and I'm still getting the issue. I also thought it was because I'm using pihole as my dns server, so I changed my dns server to 8.8.8.8. Still broken. I can load superuser, so I thought speedtest was just down. I went to isitdown and checked speedtest and it says its up. It also says beta.speedtest.net is online. When I go on my phone and go to speedtest.net using a 4g connection instead of my LAN, it loads.

pathping

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pathping www.speedtest.net

Tracing route to cs62.adn.xicdn.net [72.21.92.82]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  DESKTOP-0DJ5LG5.BreeNET [10.12.1.131]
  1     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 0 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           DESKTOP-0DJ5LG5.BreeNET [10.12.1.131]

Trace complete.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

pathping without www.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pathping speedtest.net

Tracing route to speedtest.net [151.101.0.230]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  DESKTOP-0DJ5LG5.BreeNET [10.12.1.131]
  1  10.12.1.1
  2     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 25 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           DESKTOP-0DJ5LG5.BreeNET [10.12.1.131]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  10.12.1.1

Trace complete.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: `www.speedtest.net` is not the same as `speedtest.net`

Comment: ping fails when I `ping www.speedtest.net`

Comment: So the problem is between you and www.speedtest.net. Run `pathping www.speedtest.net` and [edit] the question to include the results.

Comment: Hmm. It's not even gettting a response from your router. What does `pathping speedtest.net` output?

Comment: Seems like it gets a response from the router without adding www but then still fails. Whats bizarre to me is that this wasn't happening earlier. I've been at work all day so no one has been on the internet. Before I left for work my internet was working fine. Came home and tried to use facebook messenger to talk on the phone. Had lag issues. Tried to troubleshoot it by going to speedtest to see if I was getting high latency, and then I found out speedtest wouldn't load and apparently facebook calls are now messed up too.

Comment: I would try removing the router and connecting direct to the modem next.

Comment: Did you try turning the router off and on again?

Comment: @SpiderPig He said he did in the question.

Comment: Updated my pfsense router. Without realizing it changed my subnet from /24 to /32. That's why only some websites were working.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a [comment by the OP](https://superuser.com/questions/1209011/i-can-resolve-hostnames-but-i-cant-load-the-webpages-of-said-host#comment1763783_1209011), the problem was due to a mis-configured router:

> Without realizing it changed my subnet from /24 to /32. That's why only some websites were working.

Apparently the router was able to communicate with the configured DNS servers and therefore properly resolve DNS lookups. However, due to the invalid mask, the router couldn't actually communicate with the Internet host.

**Moral of the story:** Check and double-check any recent changes to the environment when things stop working.